# plyr.js (video player ) not working on IOS cordova

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, youtube-api

> I am using cordova for building iOS application.Need to play youtube video on application and access the all controls like timeupdate,seek,ended and other.

JS used:  Plyr.js [Player js](https://plyr.io/)

I am able to access on http/https ,android (cordova) app. While accessing on IOS platfrom getting following error.

```
Unable to post message to https://www.youtube.com. Recipient has origin file://.
```

and

```
Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.youtube.com" 
from accessing a frame with origin "file://". 
The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https",
the frame being accessed has a protocol of "file".
Protocols must match.
```

**In my html file i have added following**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready file:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api https://www.youtube.com/ https://s.ytimg.com https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"/>
```

what i am missing?

same issue ref:[check here](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/issues/99)